# Is it possible to authenticate dropbox automatically inside a shinyapps.io instance?

Tags: r, shiny, dropbox, shinydashboard, rdrop2

I'm attempting to allow dropbox authentication on my shiny app by following the tutorial on this page https://deanattali.com/blog/shiny-persistent-data-storage/. Unfortunately the solution to authenticating is manually downloading the .httr-oauth file and uploading it to the shinyapps.io server with the rest of the app files. I don't want to use this solution for security reasons (my code is written to delete the httr-oauth file at the end of a session).

On my local machine, I run the app and click a "dropbox" actionButton and it launches a dropbox authentication page through my browser, once I click accept it downloads the .httr-oauth file to my computer. At this point the app works as intended.

Once on shinyapps.io though, I click the same actionButton and nothing happens. When I look at the logs I see this output:

```
2020-01-07T05:06:56.868530+00:00 shinyapps[1632564]: Adding .httr-oauth to .gitignore
2020-01-07T05:06:56.884364+00:00 shinyapps[1632564]: Waiting for authentication in browser...
2020-01-07T05:06:56.884645+00:00 shinyapps[1632564]: Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
2020-01-07T05:06:56.886158+00:00 shinyapps[1632564]: Please point your browser to the following url: 
2020-01-07T05:06:56.886474+00:00 shinyapps[1632564]: https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXX
```

On top of this as far as I can tell, if I was even able to allow the user to follow the link directly it would likely produce an error as the client_id redirects to a localhost:1410.

I haven't tried much, I'm relatively new to R and very new to shiny (first app), so I'm at a loss. The searching on stack exchange I've already done has mentioned using Rselenium to follow the links, but this was for a much simpler issue and I'm not sure if I could get it to work.

Any help, even just pointing me in the right direction would be useful.

EDIT: Relevent code

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

    observeEvent(input$upload,
                     rdrop2::drop_auth())
}
```

rdrop2::drop_upload takes the parameter supplied and uploads that local file to dropbox. If it can't find an authentication credential it initiates a new authentication request. When I run the app on my local machine, it launches a browser window asking me if I'll give rdrop2 permission, then downloads a httr-oauth file.

Comment: Maybe you could share the relevant code.

Comment: https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/215 is an older Github issue thread, but there are some helpful links you can use to template out some adaptations to https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2/blob/master/R/drop_auth.R

Comment: @SimonWoodward added relevent code, its not much, basically just one function from the rdrop2 package.

Comment: Where does it get filename() from? I think you need to make upload_to_dropbox() a reactive function inside server, not a regular function..

Comment: @SimonWoodward nah drop_upload() needs to authenticate before it attempts to do anything with the filename, so it hasn't even reached that point yet. Just to confirm this I tried
```
server <- function(input, output, session){

    observeEvent(input$upload,
                     rdrop2::drop_auth())
}
```
Which is a function that only does the authentication part, the same problem arose. Infact I'll update my relevent code to this because it more clearly outlines the problem.